# Laravel 8 - How to get product id in ImagesController store function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Somebody help please, i'm new to laravel and i'm building an ecommerce site. I have  products table and images table. Images table has product_id as foreign key. After creating a product successfully, i'm trying to store images for the product. How do i grab the product_id in my ImagesController store function so it can be saved in the database?

Here is my images table

```
 Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
                $table->string('imagenames');
                $table->timestamps();
    
                $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
            });
```

create.blade.php for the image input

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('images.post') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
          <div class="control-group">
              <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product_id }}"/>
              <input type="file" name="filenames[]" class="form-control" multiple/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:10px">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

And here is my ImageController store function

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'product_id' => 'required|exists:products,id',
        'imagenames' => 'required',
        'imagenames.*' => 'mimes:png,jpeg,jpg'
    ]);
    $product = Product::find($request->product_id);

    if($request->hasfile('imagenames')) {
        foreach($request->image('imagenames') as $image) {
            $imagename= time() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->storeAs('public/product_images', $imagename);
            $data[] = $imagename;
        }
    }


    
    $image= new Image(); 
    $image->imagenames= json_encode($data);
    $image->save($image);
    return back()->with('success', 'Your images were successfully uploaded!');
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing

Comment: i'm trying to save product_id along with images in images table

Comment: the you need to pass that variable to ```create.blade.php```

Comment: I'm getting this error - "$product_id is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

when you prepare $image for storing just give it product_id

```
$image= new Uploadfile();
$image= new File($data); 
$image->imagenames= json_encode($data);
$image->product_id= $request->input('product_id');
```

Comment: do i need to add an input field for  product_id in my create.blade.php file?

Comment: yes, you already check that in your request validation: $this->validate($request, [
        'product_id' =>

Comment: passing $product_id as the value of the  input field shows up this error -$product_id is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should add `product_id` to object

```
$this->validate($request, [
        'product_id' => 'required|exists:products,id',
        'imagenames' => 'required',
        'imagenames.*' => 'mimes:png,jpeg,jpg'
    ]);
    $product = Product::find($request->product_id);

    if($request->hasfile('imagenames')) {
        foreach($request->image('imagenames') as $image) {
            $imagename= time() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->storeAs('public/product_images', $imagename);
            $data[] = $imagename;
        }
    }

    $image= new Image(); 
    $image->imagenames= json_encode($data);
    $image->product_id = $request->product_id ;
    $image->save($image);
    return back()->with('success', 'Your images were successfully uploaded!');
```

Comment: Trying to upload an image i get this error - "The product id field is required."  So i added an input field for product_id in my create.blade.php file (as show in the updated code), now i get this error - "$product_id is undefined"